# sending mail failure in asp.net using c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sendmail

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sending email in .NET through Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail)

This mail code is working in localhost i.e on my computer but when i uopload it on server it is not working.
The error is : Failure sending mail. please tell me where is the problem.

```
 if (Session["userinfo"] != null)
     {

         lblTest.Text = Session["userinfo"].ToString();
         MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
         msg.From = new MailAddress("shop.bcharya@gmail.com");
         msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("bcc@dr.com"));
         msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("info@yzentech.com"));
         msg.Subject = "Mail from BcharyaCorporation.online shopping site";
         msg.Body = ""+lblTest.Text+"  wants to buy some products. please contact with him/her";
         SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient();
         sc.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
         // sc.Port = 25;
         sc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("shop.bcharya@gmail.com", "mypassword");
         sc.EnableSsl = true;
         try
         {
             sc.Send(msg);
             lblPayment.Text = "Sorry. Currently we are out of online payment service. We will contact you for payment process. Thank you for buying this product.";

         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             lblPayment.Text=ex.Message.ToString();
             Response.Write(ex.Message);
         }

     }
```

Comment: Can you provide the details of the exception that you get?

Comment: no others error details are showing there only showing  Failure sending mail. i am writing the code in catch block please view the edit @ ryadavilli

Comment: What i meant was can you check the exception type, inner exception, etc.... That should give you an idea of what went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

For gmail mail settings add Port number too

```
sc.Port = 587;
```

after this line

```
sc.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
```

Comment: wait wait. the mail is sending only in gmail not in other mail the error is:  The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at @sajanyamaha

Comment: Please replace "mypassword" with your password for "shop.bcharya@gmail.com"

Comment: yes i am using my own password there.

Comment: Now try adding sc.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

Comment: no the same error is showing

Answer (score 1):

Only use port 587 and SSL if the SMTP server supports that (GMail and Hotmail for example). Some servers just use port 25 and no SSL.

Answer (score 0):

Use below method and then check :

SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient(string); //sends e-mail by using the specified SMTP server

Comment: Which is equivalent to first creating an SmtpClient and then setting the Host property, which OP has already done.

Comment: can you please tell me what do you want to mean by specefied SMTP server. @rr_only4you

Comment: i have used below code for sending a mail and it works :System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient client = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient("10.0.0.101");// please add your port number
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

Answer (score 0):

You can use this below given code for sending email. Here sending the error details through email is one method. Try this code for sending email.

```
using System.Web.Mail
public static bool SendErrorEmail(string to, string cc, string bcc, string subject,    string body, MailPriority priority, bool isHtml)
{
 try
{
using (SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient())
{
using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage())
 {
 MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress(“yourmail@domain.com”, “Your name”);
 // You can specify the host name or ipaddress of your server
 smtpClient.Host = “mail.yourdomain.com”; //you can specify mail server IP address here
 //Default port is 25
 smtpClient.Port = 25;
 NetworkCredential info = new NetworkCredential(“yourmail@domain.com”, “your password”);
 smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
 smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
 smtpClient.Credentials = info;
 //From address will be given as a MailAddress Object
 message.From = from;
 message.Priority = priority;
 // To address collection of MailAddress
 message.To.Add(to);
 message.Subject = subject;
 // CC and BCC optional
 if (cc.Length > 0)
 {
 message.CC.Add(cc);
 }
 if (bcc.Length > 0)
 {
 message.Bcc.Add(bcc);
 }
 //Body can be Html or text format;Specify true if it is html message
 message.IsBodyHtml = isHtml;
 // Message body content
 message.Body = body;
 // Send SMTP mail
 smtpClient.Send(message);
 }
 }
 return true;
 }
 catch (Exception ee)
 {
 Logger.LogError(ee, “Error while sending email to ” + toAddress);
 throw;
 }
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me for sending mail should i create my own mail server from my hosting site address? Please help me.@AndrewBarber